# Typecast Overloading On Union Without Overloading +=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unions

```
union word{
    uint16_t value;

    struct{
        uint8_t low;
        uint8_t high;
    };


    inline  word(uint16_t value) noexcept
        :value(value)
    {}


    inline word &operator=(uint16_t rhs) noexcept{
        value = rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    inline operator uint16_t() const noexcept{
        return value;
    }
}
```

I am trying to define a little endian 2 byte type where it is easy to access the low and high byte.  In addition, I want the "word" type to act completely like a uint16_t when calling any arithmetic operator.  Hence, I have overloaded the typecast operator for uint16_t.

But I have run into a slight problem:

```
word w1 = 5;
w1 = w1 + w1;  //this works fine due to implicit conversion
w1 += w1; //fails to compile.  lhs will not implicitly convert
```

I understand why it fails to compile. I'd like to have to avoid overloading all of the arithmetic operators such as +=, -=, &=, |=, etc.  Is there anyway to avoid having to define all of the operators?  It is likely I will need most of them.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
inline operator uint16_t() const noexcept{
   return value;
}
```

When you do

```
w1 += w1;
```

the left hand `w1` is implicitly converted to a `uint16_t`. However, you are actually returning a *copy* of `w1.value` which, as a result of the conversion, is a temporary object. And *you are not allowed to assign to a temporary object*. And if you magically can, the changes will not reflect to `w1.value`, something you do not want.

To solve your problem, return a *reference* of `value` instead, and make the conversion function not `const`, as you would absolutely want `value` to be modifiable.

```
inline operator uint16_t&() noexcept{
   return value;
}
```

[Here is a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=266ff6ba17d9c85ea8b50d76acd47858-d6c803482d553f395422ddf5510f4bb0) showing that the solution works.

---

However, I recommend you to read this question: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Explicitly overloading the operators of your class would be much safer and predictable than relying on implicit conversions, which sometimes would yield weird results and compile errors.